# The client XXX does not have authorization to perform action over scope or the scope is invalid

Tags: azure-rbac

I created an Azure AD Application added user_impersonation permission and generated access token using the `https://management.azure.com/.default` scope

```
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/XX/oauth2/v2.0/token
    
    client_id:
    client_secret:
    scope:https://management.azure.com/.default
    grant_type:client_credentials
```

I am referring to this Microsoft document to delete Azure resource by mentioning its ID

[Resources - Delete By Id - REST API (Azure Resource Management) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/delete-by-id)

But it threw me the error

```
Status Code(403): 'Forbidden', Response from server: '{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client ' ' with object id 'XXXX ' does not have authorization to perform action over scope or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}'
```

I am Global Admin and granted required permissions too what else am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the Service Principal doesn't have the required roles to perform the action.

**To resolve the error,** try adding `contributor` role to the Azure AD Application to delete any resource like below:

[image]

You can also assign specific roles based on your requirement or resource type.

I generated **access token** by using parameters like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/4ffc5c85-c24e-4acb-b4dc-XXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:0e5df122-c780-4ac6-b6e9-13XXXXX
client_secret:*******
scope:https://management.azure.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

I assigned **`Virtual Machine Contributor`** role to the Service Principal like below:

[image]

After assigning the role, **I am able to delete the resource by its ID successfully** like below:

[image]